# for each with array w/ multiple items

Tags: bash, shell

I'm working on a script that downloads things.

In the script I need to correlate a name and a URL that will be downloaded repeatedly (hence the script)

```
name1,url1
name2,url2
name3,url3


command $NAME $URL
```

So I want a for each loop that goes through my list of names and respective urls. What's the best way to accomplish this? Not interested at this time in keeping those lists in an external file or anything. In the script is where I would like it for this example.

Comment: Is the name somehow significant?  If it's a filename, why not just have that be part of the URL?

Comment: The name is significant. Yes. It becomes part of a directory structure.

Answer (score 4):

`bash` is quite limited on that front. You may want to try other shells.

With `zsh` (you're already using `zsh` syntax as you didn't quote your variables in `command $NAME $URL`):

```
for name url (
  name1 url1
  name2 url2
  name3 url3
) command $name $url
```

With `bash` or other POSIX shell, you could do:

```
while IFS=, read <&3 -r name url; do
  {
    command "$name" "$url"
  } 3<&-
done 3<< "EOF"
name1,url1
name2,url2
name3,url3
EOF
```

That means the values can't contain commas or newlines¹ though.

Recent versions of `bash` also support associative arrays using a syntax looking more like that of ksh93 than of `zsh`. So if the names are unique, you could do:

```
typeset -A pairs
pairs=(
  [name1]=url1
  [name2]=url2
  [name3]=url3
)
for name in "${!pairs[@]}"; do
  url=${pairs[$name]}
  command "$name" "$url"
done
```

That would also work in `ksh93`. Beware the quoting rules vary slightly between both. In `zsh`, the associative array definition syntax is more straightforward and the normal quoting rules apply:

```
pairs=(name1 url1 name2 url2 name3 url3)
```

Which you can put on several lines:

```
pairs=(
  name1 url1
  name2 url2
  name3 url3
)
```

**2021 edit**: note that `zsh` now also support the `hash=([key]=value)` ksh93 syntax and `bash` now supports the `hash=(key value)` zsh syntax

Beware the order is not preserved though and that `bash` associative arrays don't support an empty key.

`ksh93` supports multi-dimensional arrays, so you could do:

```
pairs=((name1 url1) (name2 url2) (name3 url3))
for ((i = 0; i < ${#pairs[@]}; i++)); do
  name=${pairs[i][o]} url=${pairs[i][1]}
  command "$name" "$url"
done
```

---

<sup>¹ or NULs though NULs can't be passed to commands that are executed with the `execve()` system call, and strictly speaking, the *name* part can't contain comas but the *url* part could as long as there are at least 2 or that if there's only one, it's not at the end, because of the way `$IFS` are interpreted for splitting in shells other than `zsh`.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could create a here-document that's written to a temporary file and then processed.  The temporary file will automatically be removed so no manual cleanup is required.

```
#!/bin/bash
mylist=/var/tmp/$$
trap 'rm -f ${mylist}' EXIT
cat << _EOF_ > ${mylist}
name1 url1
name2 url2
name3,url3
_EOF_
while read name url
do
    printf "%s %s\n" ${name} ${url}
done < ${mylist}
```

Answer (score 1):

At beginning i drove my mind to something complicated like associative arrays.
Then i realized that can be done as easy as bellow, considering that you have as many names as urls:

```
root@debian:a=( "name1,url1" "name2,url2" "name3,url3" );while IFS="," \ 
read -r name url;do echo "command $name $url";done<<<$(printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}")
command name1 url1
command name2 url2
command name3 url3
```

All you need is to store names and urls in the same array (a in my test) together, separated i.e by comma.

Answer (score 1):

With `bash`, you can do it as follow:

1. Create an array

   ```
   my_array=(
     name1 url1
     name2 url2
     name3 url3
   )
   ```
2. Get the number of items in the array

   ```
   count=${#my_array[@]}
   ```

   Notice `count` is the total number of items. We take that in account in our next loop.
3. Go through the array for a `for` loop

   ```
   for (( i = 0; i < count; i += 2 ))
   do
     echo "Name = ${my_array[i + 0]}"
     echo " URL = ${my_array[i + 1]}"
   done
   ```

   *Note: the ... + 0 is not required, it clearly shows you get item at position 0 and position 1.*

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a plain bash script will work for you:

```
pairs=( "name1,url1" "name2,url2" "name3,url3" )

for pair in "${pairs[@]}"; do
    IFS=, read name url <<<"${pair}"
    printf "%s %s\n" "${name}" "${url}"
    command "${name}" "${url}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit overly complex in it's own right but sticking with the format that most others have given, but not invoking IFS I'd use

```
pairs=( "name1,url1" "name2,url2" "name3,url3" )

for pair in "${pairs[@]}"; do
    #Create an array in itself, of the two values.
    tmpArr=(`echo $pair | tr ',' ' '`)

    #Then either use Array Indexing on the array ie. 
    #Or place the offsets in their own variables. ie Run=${tmpArr[0] ...;
    command ${tmpArr[0]} ${tmpArr[1]}
done
```

Eliminates the need for Temporary Files, no real cleanup needed, as long as used within a script which Sha-Bangs initially, or made local in a function, which is the way I've done most of my scripting, keeping syntax as close to 'C' as possible. Sticks to my bash motto as well, "If you want to do it, someone's done it before, and made it a module, so don't do the work over..."

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading two comma-separated items from a file (or *stdin*) per your example data, you can use a simple loop

```
while IFS=, read -r name url
do
    your_command "$name" "$url"
done <your_file
```

Omit the redirection from `your_file` if you prefer to read from *stdin*.

If the data is already in an array it depends largely on how it's stored. Perhaps it's simple sequential entries, each a comma-separated pair:

```
nameurls=(
    name1,url1
    name2,url2
    name3,url3
)

for nameurl in "${nameurls[@]}"
do
    name=${nameurl%%,*} url=${nameurl#*,}
    command "$name" "$url"
done
```

Suggestions with an associative array have already been make in other answers so I'll not include that here